# Swiper slide custom counter (fractions)

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I use swiper slider and have counter fractions. Its counting well but I need to count = (all slides - 1). For example if I have 20 slides, I want to show the total number 19.Any ideas how I can do this? I use regular js from their website. Here what I have:

```
var gallery = new Swiper('.left-side-slider-gallery', {
  slidesPerView: '1',
  pagination: {
  el: '.jail-app-left-side-fractions',
  type: 'fraction',
  },
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `custom` type, and a `renderCustom` function, as mentioned in the [docs](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#pagination-parameters):

```
var gallery = new Swiper('.left-side-slider-gallery', {
  slidesPerView: 1,
  pagination: {
    el: '.jail-app-left-side-fractions',
    type: 'custom',
    renderCustom: function (swiper, current, total) {
        return current + '/' + (total - 1); 
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Works Perfect! Thank You!

Comment: This question and answer saved my day! It worked like a gem. Thanks @blex and Sten Smith